# Determine OneDrive synchronisation folders

Tags: onedrive

Looking for pointers as to how to determine the path used locally for OneDrive. I'm aware of the existence of the REST API but that's got a huge learning curve so any shortcuts to determine that it's (for example):

> C:\Users\username\OneDrive - SharePoint Tenant Name

The OneDrive environment variable can't be used if the user has both a personal and Office 365 (was OneDrive for Business) account configured as it then references the personal folder:

> C:\Users\username\OneDrive

Another complexity is that the user *could* have multiple Office 365 OneDrive accounts configured so I suspect I need to some code walk through the OneDrive configuration. But haven't a clue where that is held.

Comment: Does anyone has an answer for that?

Answer (score 2):

Some new environment variables have appeared in Windows 10 1809:
OneDrive, OneDriveCommercial the user's OneDrive for Business folder
OneDriveConsumer  the user's personal OneDrive folder

Makes life easier!

Comment: A little easier but you still can't rely on the variables 100% because people can logon to multiple OneDrive business accounts at the same time - and there is only one set of environment variables